# Как в папке переименовать файлы оканчивающиеся на _right.png

Tags: linux, grep

Приведу пример так будет нагляднее.

```
top_case_right.png => top_case_new_right.png
```

есть общий признак у файлов _right.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rename 's/_right\.png/_new_right\.png/' *_right.png
```

Если утилита *rename* у Вас не установлена - просто установите её.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например sed'ом:

```
ls | sed -rne 's/(.*)(_right\.png)$/mv "&" "\1_new\2"/e'
```

Comment: zOMG, зачем *sed* там, где можно использовать встроенные паттерны shell? Ну и на закуску, зачем листать все файлы, если можно только те, которые собрались переименовывать?

Comment: @0andriy предложите вы своё решение.